# Verify if _tmkdir succeeds

Tags: c, directory

Can anybody help me in finding out how to verify that `_tmkdir` succeeded.
For example i wish to create a file within another folder. This folder i will create at runtime. So i will give the following command.

```
sFilePath = sFilePath + _T("\\P-Series Communication Logs");
_tmkdir( sFilePath );
```

where `sFilePath` would initially contain a software installation path which will be obtained from registry.

i wish to know if `_tmkdir` succeeded or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the return value of `_tmkdir` to see if the call succeeded. If it failed, the `errno` global variable indicates the reason for failure:

```
int result = _tmkdir(sFilePath);
if (result == 0) {
    // succeeded
}
else {
    // failed
    if (errno == EEXIST) {
        // already exists!
    }
}
```

For more information, look at the MSDN documentation for `_tmkdir` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fkk4dzw.aspx) and `errno` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3ayayh1.aspx).

I hope this helps!